# 'MSSQL' encountered unexpected exception of type 'InvalidOperationException' with HResult 'x80131509' while opening connection

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

When I am trying to load a query into a tabular dateset (from a devops docker image) I will get the following error:

```
raise DatasetValidationError(error_message + '\n' + str(e), e)
azureml.data.dataset_error_handling.DatasetValidationError: Cannot load any data from the datastore using the SQL query "<azureml.data.datapath.DataPath object at 0x>". Please make sure the datastore and query is correct.

Error Code: ScriptExecution.DatabaseConnection.Unexpected
Failed Step: 9ad57100-4870-49d2-a32f-1c9c15c244e0
Error Message: ScriptExecutionException was caused by DatabaseConnectionException.
  DatabaseConnectionException was caused by UnexpectedException.
    'MSSQL' encountered unexpected exception of type 'InvalidOperationException' with HResult 'x80131509' while opening connection.
      Internal connection fatal error.
```

I believe that I have allowed the connection in firewall (I might not have done it quite right).

I don't get the error when I am running it from the notebook (on the compute instance).

Answer (score 0):

Is the code that is running on the compute instance the exact same as the docker image? If so, it's likely that the firewall is causing connectivity issues. One way of checking this is to (be cautious) disable the firewall and see if the connectivity issue is gone.

If you're comfortable sharing the firewall/network configurations, that will also help troubleshoot this.